# How i can return Expected exception: java.util.InputMismatchException in my java function

Tags: java, exception

**This is my function**

```
public Object check(long number) {
        long root = 0;
            while (number > 0 || root > 9) {
                if (number == 0) {
                    number = root;
                    root = 0;
                }

                root += number % 10;
                number /= 10;
            }
        return root;
}
```

**I want to pass this test case how can i sov it **

```
     @Test(expected = InputMismatchException.class)
        public void testInvalidInput() {
            digitalRoot.check(-87625L);
        }
```

Comment: This will not enter the while loop. What is the condition to throw the exception?

Comment: at the beginning of the method you need `if (number < 0) throw new InputMismatchException();`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (number < 0) throw new InputMismatchException(number + "");
```

Add this as the first line of the method and it will throw the exception you need.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: -87625
```

You can change the error message to provide more context.